# A bunch of errors while creating new project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, project

I am using android studio version 2.2.3 and got these errors after creating a project. The android version is default as android 4.03 icream .

[image]

Here is the gradle image:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Edit your question by posting build.gradle file

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: i also added junit-4.12.jar in the libs but that didn't solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I've experience this just yesterday when starting a new project with a fresh Android Studio Installation.

You need to be connected to Internet first before starting the project. Android Studio need to downloads all the dependencies that are missing for your project.

The problem is happened either because you're not **connected to Internet** or Android Studio is **blocked by firewall**.

Answer (score 0):

removing or commenting the following line solved the problem but i have to do it every time i create a new project
1)go to gradle scripts, open build.gradle (module:app)
2)comment or remove the following lines 
*testinstrumentationrunner "....."
*comment the whole body of dependencies except the one with androidtestcompile "...support:Appcompat" and comment the other lines